# Seeking a point/level module to encourage user activity

Tags: 7, users

I have a very new site. Users have occassionaly popped in to say "hi" and that's about it.

I suspect a chicken and egg situation - I won't get content until there is content.

I seem to recall that Drupal Commons (sadly my server seems too  slow for it) has a system which is fairly standard in forums, where users get points and gainlevels for activity.

Is there something like that which is simple to add for a new admin on D7?

Thanks in advance

---

p.s. That's at its simplest, from an old school forumer; maybe I need +/-or "like/dislike" or new-fangled facebooky stuff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For various voting and similar systems you could check these modules (including some quotes from their project pages):

1. [Voting API](https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi):

> ... helps developers who want to use a standardized API and schema for storing, retrieving, and tabulating votes for Drupal content.

2. [Fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar):

> ... adds a clean, attractive voting widget to nodes and comments and any entity.

3. [User Points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints):

> ... provides an API for users to gain or lose points for performing certain actions on your site. In conjunction with other modules, such as the Userpoints Nodes and Comments users can accumulate points for actions such as posting nodes, commenting or moderation duties.

4. [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag):

> ... is a flexible flagging system that is completely customizable by the administrator. Using this module, the site administrator can provide any number of flags for nodes, comments, users, and any other type of entity. Some possibilities include bookmarks, marking important, friends, or flag as offensive. With extensive views integration, you can create custom lists of popular content or keep tabs on important content.

Comment: Ok, those look good. I guess I was thinking more along the lines of classical "reward activity" and give users points for every post, and then possibly refing it with the more modern "like/dislike" things. Both are good, but I am an "older gentleman" and more familiar with"points make prizes". I will look into these. Thanks. And +1

Comment: The userpoints module will allow you to award users points for performing certain actions on your site.

Answer (score 1):

I also like the [rate](http://drupal.org/project/rate) module.

When launching any new social site I suggest you do anything you can to create enough compelling content to make it look like an already busy and interesting site.
You could create content yourself or invite friends to create content for you.

Daily "teaser" questions will also help to get activity on the site.

In the beginning you'll have to "fake it" until you make it ;-)